# Pull from a nested object - MongoDB PHP Driver

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e7b8f17713989198839194"),
    "uuid" : "dbf4966a-1b94-45d9-ad65-11d4c1a84d08",
    "economy_tokens" : 18367,
    "player_name" : "JoshTheDev",
    "player_name_lower" : "joshthedev",
    "last_login" : ISODate("2015-05-24T22:28:50.456Z"),
    "login_count" : 4236,
    "names" : [ 
        "JoshTheDev"
    ],
    "package" : {
        "hub_fly" : true
    },
    "first_login" : ISODate("2015-02-21T09:40:05.069Z"),
    "economy_gems" : 999993201,
    "economy_nether_drops" : 100068
}
```

And I wish to remove the "hub_fly" from the package object. How would I do this (PHP Driver, Java driver is easy for this)? I've tried different variants such as $pull and $unset with no avail. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your documents structure `package` is an object and remove in object data you should use mongo [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) and query as :

```
db.collectionName.update({},{"$unset":{"package.hub_fly":""}},false,true)
```

`false` for upsert and `true` for multi

And this should be in the java driver as below :

```
BasicDBObject unsetDocument = new BasicDBObject();
unsetDocument.append("$unset", new BasicDBObject().append("package.hub_fly", ""));
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
collection.update(searchQuery, unsetDocument,false,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

```
$a1 = $a['package'];
if(($key = array_search($package, $a1)) !== false) {
    unset($a1[$key]);
}
$serversCollection->update(array("uuid" => $a['uuid']), array('$set' => array("package" => $a1)));
```